# Highlight textarea based on user given keywords

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have successfully used below script to get predefined text highlighted in the textarea.
http://www.strangeplanet.fr/work/jquery-highlighttextarea/

How it is possible to get the predefined text to be changed on the fly? E.g. user write "green" in specific input box and then "green-words" are highlighted in textarea?

Comment: It seems that this plugin has no "update" API method, so simple reinitialization on 'change' event, as @F. Calderan stated, should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#input-id").bind('keypress',function () {
    var word = $(this).val();
    if (word) {
        $("textarea").highlightTextarea({
            words: [word]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Will it reinit the plugin twice when you click any key?

Comment: I got this solution to work but it makes typing slow. Could someone please tell what is the bug in on change method provided by Calderan? [http://jsbin.com/avodoj/](http://jsbin.com/avodoj/)

Comment: The reason of slowness is that `keypress`, `keydown` and `keyup` events make highlightTextarea reinitialize after each keyboard press within your input field. Event `change` illustrated by Calderan triggers when you move the focus out of the the input field. It helps to avoid slowness when typing but has a drawback that highlighting is not working on-the-fly. The main problem of highlightTextarea plugin is the absence of API methods which provide fast updating.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try something like

```
<input type="text" id="wordtohighlight">
<textarea>lorem ipsum green sit dolor amet green</textarea>
```

Js/jQuery

```
$('#wordtohighlight').on('change', function() {
    var v = $(this).val();
    $("textarea").highlightTextarea({
         words: [v]
    });
}
```

With this code snippet you call the plugin when input changes (e.g. when `input text` loses focus/you click elsewhere on the page) . If you prefer you could try to use `keyup` event

Answer (score 0):

Hook into the keydown event of the input box and change the words array.

I have never used the jQuery plugin you linked to but something like this should work:

```
$("#target").keydown (function () {
    $("textarea").highlightTextarea({
          words: [$(this).val()]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#input-id").keydown (function () {
    var word = $(this).val();
    if (word) {
        word += '-words';
        $("textarea").highlightTextarea({
            words: [word]
        });
    }
});
```